# How do you pass arguments to a function called within another function?

Tags: r

I am using an orphaned R library ([*wmtsa*](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wmtsa/index.html)). One of it's functions creates a continuous wavelet transform (`wavCWT()`) that returns a wavelet object and it can be plotted by calling the traditional `plot()` function. Unfortunately, the way the function is written does not allow me to change some typical plot parameters. In particular, I cannot set `axes=F` and I am forced to have the axes plotted all the time. This is not helpful as I want to add extra layers to my device and the axes are different and it they are offset.

Is there a way to pass the argument to the method that is calling the plot() function?

If this is not possible I am afraid I will have to modify the source code. If this is the case, where should I look in order to modify the methods of this kind of object?

I found the [source](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/R/wav_xform.R?root=wmtsa) of the methods but my hacking skills are limited and I am a bit lost.

Example:

```
 library(wmtsa)   # assuming you have installed the package wmtsa
 wavCWT(sin(rnorm(1000)))
 plot(W, power.stretch=0.5)
```

produces this plot:

[image]

but if I try to remove axes with `axes=F` I get the following message:

```
plot(W, power.stretch=0.5, axes=F)
Error in plot.default(NA, NA, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, type = "n", xaxs = xaxs,  : 
formal argument "axes" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Comment: The title is a bit misleading.  The real question (I think) is:  "How do you pass arguments to a function called within another function?"  And the general answer is: make sure the parent function is written correctly so as to allow this :-( .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to change the source, but only very slightly. On line 269-270 of `wav_xform.R`, inside the `plot.wavCMT` function change the line:

```
image(data$x, data$y, imageScale(data$z, power.stretch=power.stretch), ...,
  xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab, axes=TRUE)
```

to

```
image(data$x, data$y, imageScale(data$z, power.stretch=power.stretch), ...,
  xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab)
```

The reason is that ellipsis (`...`)- that means "take any extra arguments to the `plot` function and pass them to the `image` function". However, the original code had `axes=TRUE` there too, which means that if you try and pass `axes=FALSE` you'll get a `formal argument "axes" matched by multiple actual arguments` error.

Then (once you reinstall), the following works to get rid of the axes:

```
library(wmtsa)
sunspots.cwt <- wavCWT(sunspots)
plot(sunspots.cwt)  # has axes
plot(sunspots.cwt, axes=FALSE)  # does *not* have axes
```

Also note that you *can* change other common plot parameters, thanks to that ellipsis! (That's true even if you never modify the source). For example:

```
plot(sunspots.cwt, main="My great wavelet plot")  # change title
plot(sunspots.cwt, xlim=c(1750, 1850))  # change x axis range
plot(sunspots.cwt, ylim=c(0, 2))  # change y axis range
```

Answer (score 2):

The *wmtsa* package defines a `plot` method specifically for objects of class `wavCWT`. As it is a S3 method, it is called `plot.wavCWT` but it is declared as invisible as indicated by this command (after loading the package) :

```
methods(plot)
```

By default, with R, you can get the source of a function by just typing its name without parentheses. But it doesn't work here because the function is invisible. So you have to do :

```
getAnywhere(plot.wavCWT)
```

One thing you can do is copy the source code and then redefine the function with :

```
plot.wavCWT <- function (x, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, logxy = "y", power.stretch = 0.5, 
phase = FALSE, series = FALSE, series.ylab = "", zoom = NULL, 
type = "image", grid.size = 100, add = FALSE, theta = 120, 
phi = 30, ...) {
    ...paste your original code here...
}
```

And then you can modify the original code as you wish and execute your function definition to make it available to your scripts.

I'm not totally sure of the thing you need to modify to suit your needs, but there is the following block in the function definition :

```
        plot(series.time, x.series[itime], type = "l", col = "blue", 
            axes = TRUE, xlim = range(series.time), ylab = series.ylab, 
            xlab = "", xaxt = "n", xaxs = "i")
```

You can then change `axes=TRUE` to `axes=FALSE` or, better yet, add an argument `plotaxes=TRUE` to your function definition and then change `axes=TRUE` to `axes=plotaxes`.

Comment: There's no need to add a `plotaxes` argument. As long as `axes=TRUE` is removed (see my answer) you can just do `axes=FALSE` right to the plot function without any further modifications, thanks to the ellipsis.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I applied `plotaxes` to the wrong function.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Juba, the trick of using `getAnywhere()` and then add this to my library of functions made my life easier. +1

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution without altering the function code:

```
x=seq(1:10)
y=x
plot(x,y,ylab="unwanted y label",xlab="x")
mtext("unwanted y label", side=2, line=3, col="white", cex=1)
mtext("my new y label", side=2, line=3, col=1, cex=1)
```

The above code writes over the previous y label in white and then replaces the label with the desired label.